# Elastic Search connector for SPARK

Tags: elasticsearch, connector

**Use Case**:
An application uses spark to process data for 5 minutes, the data to be processed could be of several hundred thousands of records in data storage. 
The choice for data storage is Elastic Search.

**Issue**: 
Do we have a connector for the spark in elasticsearch similar to the connector in MongoDB?

https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector.

**Investigation**:
I spent a lot of time but the best I could find was a solution using search API with scroll(we can fetch the limited number of records for given number interval), but this does not fit my use-case.

Please note that my elastic search will have JSON data and we do not want to save RDD.
as mentioned in below

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark connector for ES , and data is not saved in any binary form - but RDD/Dataframe is serialized as JSON and thats what goes into Elasticsearch.

Comment: so it means, I will have to reindex my JSON document to change it to RDD format ??

Comment: Is the result of spark job an RDD  ?

Comment: The application runs in an interval, it is supposed to get a spark context and then it should process a certain duration of data using data frame.

Comment: in that case , you could just save dataframe to es with connector ... not sure what is missing

Comment: I should not save the data as dataframe (it is the constraint).
Data will be saved only in json format.

I was able to do successfully it  for MongoDB and Cassandra as they provide connector, i was hoping same for es .

Comment: I am sorry - does that mean in spark , you do not have a dataframe at the end ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain much. I will give you a background.

The primary purpose of ES is the full-text search for analysis and data has to be ingested as JSON. I am not supposed to change the ingestion process.

The application which I mentioned is currently ingesting data as spark data frame from some other source for example say S3. Now I am trying to use the same applicaiton , but get data from ES and I can add a layer where data from ES can be changed to Dataframe. But it seems there are no connector like in mongo DB.

Comment: Not sure if i understood completely - but yes - you can read data from ES into dataframes ( eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820665/scala-read-array-value-in-elasticsearch-with-spark/51169800) and you can write data to ES from dataframe using connector ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html)